# Camel exception before reaching route

Tags: exception, apache-camel, restlet

I have a restlet route as below

```
from("restlet:/api?restletMethod=GET").log("API Reached");
```

The problem is `from("restlet:/api?restletMethod=GET")` throws an exception when I send an invalid url  like `http://localhost:8080/api?query=%s%n%s`.

How to handle this exception? `onException` is not working as the request is not reaching the route

Comment: You should do from("restlet:localhost:8080/api"). And what exception do you get, and what version of Camel do you use

Comment: Also onException is for exceptions during routing, not beforehand. But some components can support to bridge the error handling, see the docs, or my book for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should configure endpoint like this.

```
RestletEndpoint endpoint = context.getEndpoint("restlet:http://localhost:8080/api", RestletEndpoint.class);
endpoint.configureProperties(Collections.singletonMap("bridgeErrorHandler", true));
```